# Error while building cordova app for release

Tags: windows, cordova, sqlite, phonegap

Getting error

> Error MSB3819 Cannot find assembly
>   "plugins\cordova-sqlite-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3.UWP\release\SQLite3.UWP\SQLite3.UWP.dll",
>   which may contain managed resources that need to be included in this
>   app package.   Please ensure that this assembly exists.
>   [platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]

While building windows app for release using visual studio 2015

Although is it working fine for debug mode.